# Make Flex 4 web application load faster

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flash-builder, performance

I made a Flex 4 web application. Upon testing locally, I already got satisfied at how it looks like. However, the swf's file size grew to around 6mb in size so when I uploaded it to my website and viewed it, it takes forever to load on a computer with quite slow internet connection. So my question is, how do I make it load faster? Should I:

- seperate it into chunks? If so **how** do I do it.
- **not** put the embedded images inside the SWF but instead, store it outside in a folder? If so, how do I make it load on the background while the user is interacting with the primarily loaded parts of the web app?

Please do help me?

Comment: What files are making it 6mb. That would take thousands of AS and MXML files. Is there some very large assets being loaded (or a lot of smaller ones)?

Comment: Hmm I think it's the embedded background images that I've put on to my SWF file. The reason I did this is because I've added a fade effect on the background images and when I reference them externally and NOT embed them, they tend to show up late and thus ruin the presentation of the fade effect.

Answer (score 3):

You should separate your application into [modules](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f22.html). Another alternative is to split it into [sub-applications](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d14.html).

Comment: @Shedo Chung-Hee Surashu: No. Typically you build up your application of components. It is simple to put these components into modules. Just read about ["Writing Modules"](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7997.html).

Answer (score 3):

Besides splitting up your application into Modules and/or sub-applications, try to use RSLs where possible. Especially the RSLs of the Flex framework.

Here's documentation on how to do this: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=rsl_09.html